# How to set fetch Firestore data into dropdown menu in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to set my Firestore data into the drop-down menu.
But When I trying to do this, I got a drop don menu like this.

[image: I got a drop don menu like this]

How to set my fetch data into the drop-down menu correctly.

This is my code...?

```
class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _cupCakeStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('cupcake')
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _cupCakeStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
        return Container(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return DropdownSearch<String>(
                  mode: Mode.MENU,
                  showSelectedItems: true,
                  items: [data["cupcake_name"]],
                  label: "Select  Category",
                  popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
                  onChanged: print,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

After Edit -
[image: Have this kind of Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `DropdownSearch` widget for each document. Instead you should create a single `DropdownSearch` widget, with all documents in the `items` property.

```
return Container(
  child: DropdownSearch<String>(
      mode: Mode.MENU,
      showSelectedItems: true,
      items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return data["cupcake_name"];
      }).toList().cast<String>(),
      label: "Select  Category",
      popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
      onChanged: print,
  ),
);
```

Comment: The argument type 'Iterable<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>?'. When I try your code I got an error like this

Comment: I updated the code to address that, but goind forward **always** first search for an error message you get, as this one is incredibly common. :-/

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.But Still the error. I tried everything..but not Working. -"The argument type 'Item' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'"

Comment: What is the `Item` in "The argument type 'Item'" referring to?

Comment: Type: QuerySnapshot<Object?>? Still I can't load my drop down sir

Comment: That update looks nothing like what I changed in my answer. Note that the `docs.map` call in my answer is under `items`, while you have i outside of `DropdownSearch`? That is the main point of my answer, and until you change that in your code, you will always end up with many dropdown menus with one item each.

Comment: Sir I update One more time. Please take a look.I really need your help

Comment: That's because `data["cupcake_name"]` is `dynamic`, since there can be many types of fields. According to https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+list%3Cdynamic%3E+to+list%3Cstring%3E+in+flutter, you can use `.cast<String>()` on the list to cast each element to the correct type. So `}).toList().cast<String>(),`

Comment: Thank You very much, Sir. You save my life as a beginner SE.❤️

Comment: You're welcome. For future problems though, I recommend taking smaller steps. If you create a `DropdownSearch` with hard-coded values first, you can more easily see how it works. Then adding the Firestore loading *after* that is typically a lot easier than trying to do everything in one go.

Comment: Ok, Sir.Thank you very much.❤️