# How Can I Remove Duplicates From DropdownMenuItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dropdown, stream-builder

I'm having an issue with duplicate DropdownMenuItem while getting the menu item's value from Firestore.

[image: My Firestore DB Structure]

I want to get all the 'from' attributes values from 'routes' collection excluding the duplicates. And i want to show them inside my DropDownButton.

My Sample Code:

```
late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> routes = Database().getRoutes();


StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream: routes,
builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
    ) {

  final data = snapshot.requireData;

  fromValue.value = data.docs[0]['from'];
  destinationValue.value = data.docs[0]['to'];

  return Column(
    children: [
      Obx(() {
        return DropdownButton(
          // Initial Value
          value: fromValue.value,
          // Down Arrow Icon
          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          underline: Container(
            height: 1,
            color: Colors.deepPurple.shade100,
          ),
          // list of items
          items: data.docs.map(
                  (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<
                    String>(
                    value: doc['from']
                        .toString(),
                    child:
                    Text(doc['from']));
              }).toList(),
          // After selecting the desired option,it will
          // change button value to selected value
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            fromValue.value = newValue.toString();
          },
        );
      }),
    ],
  );
}),
```

Method Used To Fetch Firestore Data:

```
getRoutes() {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> routes = db
    .collectionGroup("routes")
    .snapshots();

    return routes;
  }
```

Comment: Create a separate method that will return a set with unique item, like  `items: convertToItem(data.docs.)`

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69133245/10157127

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?  @YeasinSheikh

Comment: you can do it from `factionDatabaseSnapshot`

Comment: Can you reference some links please ? @Ye

Comment: Try `factionDatabaseSnapshot.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => document['name']).toSet().toList().map((name)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247506/discussion-between-risfat-and-yeasin-sheikh).